# Optimizer python function to optimize

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I need to optimize a function.
For this, I use the scipy.optimize.basinhopping function.

I have coded the function to be optimized and the function to make changes and I call the basinhopping function like this:

```
result = basinhopping(func_to_be_optimized, x0,
                  take_step=take_step,
                  niter=10, niter_success=10,
                  disp=True)
```

The x0 is the initial solution guessed.

My problem is that the func_to_be_optimized function is called a lot of times and then the take_step function is called.
But normally it must be: one call of take_step and one call of func_to_be_optimized  etc.

Moreover, the func_to_be_optimized function have a X parameter and it is modified at each call but not by my function take_step.

Why I have this issue?

Comment: "it must be: one call of take_step and one call of func_to_be_optimized etc." - why? Is that an actual restriction you have? It'd be a really weird one. The behavior you're observing is completely normal for basin hopping.

Comment: Thank you for your response! In fact, so I have used an other optimizer because basinhopping was not appropriated for my problem

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html):

The algorithm is iterative with each cycle composed of the following features

1. random perturbation of the coordinates
2. local minimization
3. accept or reject the new coordinates based on the minimized function value

Step 1. uses take_step.  step 2. (local minimization) will call your func_to_be_optimized multiple times.